# HowTo create (or find example code of) Qt widget "Property Editor" like in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt4, widget, custom-widgets

Here is my current **problem**: I'm looking for a simple tree view widget, like on the picture below. I just need tree view, not the dialog with it's filter line edit, buttons and etc. Only tree view.

I checked sources of the Qt Designer, and found the realization of that widget, but it's too complex and it will be very hard to cut needed sources from there. So here I'm:

- Maybe someone could recommend me web site with Qt widgets or any other ideas?

[image: Property Editor, Qt Designer]

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [Property Browser Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq18-propertybrowser.html) ([2013: at gitHub](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/trees/master/qtpropertybrowser)). It is easy to use.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Qt documentation moved. The new link is https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq18-propertybrowser.html (I can't edit myself)

Comment: Tested mentioned Qt Property Browser on 5.15 version of Qt, It's worked well.
Could be downloaded here https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions.git